# Redis timeout after UnableToResolvePhysicalConnection exception

Tags: azure-web-app-service, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

We are investigating an issue on an api on Azure connecting to Azure Redis Cache (tier C2 standard), since yesterday evening to today early morning (nearly 12 hours) we've seen a hundreds of timeouts to redis like this

> Timeout performing GET ????????:FV:Providers:Weather, inst: 1, mgr:
>   Inactive, err: never, queue: 318, qu: 2, qs: 316, qc: 0, wr: 1, wq: 1,
>   in: 65536, ar: 0, clientName: Items, serverEndpoint: ?????????:6380,
>   keyHashSlot: 1586, IOCP: (Busy=1,Free=999,Min=8,Max=1000), WORKER:
>   (Busy=66,Free=32701,Min=300,Max=32767

During the night we don´t receive much visits but the error still until today around 9 o´clock, the items in the redis queue were up to 7000 but the traffic to our api was very low during the night.

During the day all was ok except this afternoon during an hour when we got a peak of visitors the problem appeared again. We´ve been looking a lot of metrics, cache read/writes operations is as usual, cache hits, cpu, memory, ... all it´s ok.

Even other API´s use the same redis cache instance and they don´t suffer this issue. For this reason we think that the size of Azure Redis it´s correct if not other API´s will suffer the same problem.

Looking at logs we discovered that just two minutes before the timeout error started we got more than 200  exceptions like this

> StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException:
>   UnableToResolvePhysicalConnection on GET    at
>   StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message
>   message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server)    at
>   StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message,
>   ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server)    at
>   StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.StringGet(RedisKey key, CommandFlags
>   flags)

We guess that the two errors are related. But we don´t know if we are doing something wrong or it was an azure problem. May be StackExchange.Redis connection was corrupted after UnableToResolvePhysicalConnection exception and we have to restart API to solve the problem?

Other ideas?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StackExchange.Redis has a known problem where it will fail to reconnect under some cases even though the server is running fine.  Example: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/559

I suspect you are running into that type of issue.  You can verify that by trying to connect to Redis from some other machine.  If it connects fine, then you are likely hitting this issue.  Recreating your ConnectionMultiplexer should fix the problem.  Rebooting your client should fix it if you don't have a way to recreate the multiplexer.

I have a bunch of best practices that may help you structure your code to handle such cases, including general best practices as well as StackExchange.Redis specific recommendations. https://aka.ms/redis/bestpractices

Comment: We are going to implement the ForceReconnect. Is it Better to capture the RedisConnectionException and then call ForceReconnect, or Can we check Database.IsConnected and if false invoce ForceReconnect? Both ways will work or is it better to capture RedisConnectionException? Thanks!

Comment: I haven't done testing around checking IsConnected when deciding whether or not to reconnect, so I can't comment on the accuracy of that property.  We have had many customers implement the ForceReconnect logic as we have it currently written and it has solved their problems consistently.